# Why 888888803. == 8888888.03*100. in python is false?

Tags: python, rounding, equals, operator-keyword

Why this python code 
`print 888888803. == 8888888.03*100.`
prints False?

Comment: Because `8888888.03 * 100` is `888888802.9999999` when you calculate it in python

Comment: You seem to know the answer already because you've added the [tag:rounding] tag.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html